# Visual Studio Extension - project root folder

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing Visual Studio extension with command in the Solution Explorer. But the command menu item should be available only in the project root folder.

How can I get the project root folder?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "project root folder"? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that your command needs to be appear only if the context menu is open on a project node of the solution explorer, then its parent must be like this:

```
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE" />
```